# Speed up direct MP3 streaming on Apache?

Tags: apache, centos, audio-streaming, webmin

I have a CentOS 7 (64bit) VPS powered by OpenVZ. 1.70 GHz CPU, 1GB RAM, 1TB SSD, 1 Gbps port speed. I'm running Webmin and Apache (2.4.6) as a virtual host. No other software is running on the VPS, and I'm using it as a file server to link directly to MP3 files over HTTP (I have around 50GB of MP3s hosted).

The MP3 files are podcasts, so typically around 50mb - 100mb in size. The problem I'm having is it can take 5 or 6 seconds of buffering before an MP3 file start to stream. The domain I'm using is setup with cloudflare and loads very quickly, download speeds and ping times are also good (around 50ms), but the delay before an MP3 starts to stream is a bit of an inconvenience.

Is there anything I can do in Apache to speed up the buffering? Or is the buffering just a result of having a low-spec VPS?

All settings in Webmin and Apache are pretty much default, as I'm more use to working with IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I solved this by disabling file streaming through the Cloudflare proxy. Streaming files in this was can cause performance issues, as outlined on this page:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169706-Can-I-use-Cloudflare-with-a-streaming-music-or-video-site-

I also upgraded my VPS to double the amount of RAM. I apologise for this not being an Apache / CentOS issue, but hopefully someone with a similar issue will find this helpful.